# Bicycle Lock Combination

Tags: rebus, password

My bicycle lock looks like this:

[image]

---

This rebus helps me remember the combination:

[image]

---

I read it left to right, top to bottom.

**What's the combination, and why?**

Comment: If this is solved, why isn't it marked as answered?

Comment: @qwertylpc Well, it's because many (most?) people see a puzzle that has already been solved, and are not interested in it, since it is solved. If I wait a few hours to accept an answer, then more people get to enjoy it, and see it, and as a bonus, more people might up-vote it. Also, in some cases a late answer may be better than the original correct answer, and that puzzler might not have even looked at the puzzle if it was already accepted.

Comment: As an aside, please don't use that lock to lock an actual bike. A cable lock is, at best, a mild inconvenience to thieves. All it means is they have to use bolt cutters to steal your bike in seconds, instead of just riding off on it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby shhh don't give them ideas!  ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your combination is

> 21210

This is found by

> Shifting the letters in each word by the number indicated to get the name of a number and then combining their digits.

Therefore, the pieces are:

> LOG $\Rightarrow$ TWO
> BAR $\Rightarrow$ ONE
> RUM $\Rightarrow$ TWO
> UFO $\Rightarrow$ TEN

Comment: nicely done. will you add to your answer, "If you upvote this answer, please also upvote the puzzle" ?  haha jk

Comment: @JLee Well, I gave it +1 at least. It's not something I've seen before. It took me an extra minute to realize that WOOD+8 didn't mean anything.

Comment: Where does the final zero come from?

Comment: @COTO From the ten.

Comment: Oh... right. You know, that right there would have disqualified the correct solution for me, because *not only* would such an interpretation be missing a digit, the fourth number would overflow the counter. You just blew my mind. :D